# how to replace a str with another str in an input

Tags: python, translation

How do I replace strings in a list with another string? For example, I want to replace "A" with "[c:16399:0/]" and "B" with
"[c:16400:0/]". I want to do this with every character in user input. I have tried the .replace function however, I was only able to replace 1 character at a time and I don't know how to replace multiple at the same time.

I hope this edit clarifies my question, Thanks!

Comment: What do the numbers in your desired output correspond to?

Comment: There is no Python syntax that even comes close to the representation of your desired result. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you seek.

Comment: don't post images of code, jut copy/paste the text

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: that code does nothing of the thing you ask, it just gets a few strings from the user and transforms it to a list of chars in a convoluted way

Comment: what is the use of these `[c:16399:0/]` strings

Comment: @rioV8 it is to change the font of the GUI in metal gear rising, My friend requested I make this code for him to streamline the process. Hope this answers your question!

Comment: @Joe, it is to change the font in a game my friend is modding (metal gear rising)

Comment: I just didn't want to assume that the numbers already correspond to Unicode code points in some way, which is why I asked what the numbers represent - not what they're going to be used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to transform the characters to the other string

```py
def newstring(c):
    return f"[c:{16399+ord(c)-ord('A')}:0/]"

startstring = "ABCD WORLD"
transformed = [ newstring(c) for c in startstring ]
```

If you want a new string use

```py
transformed = ''.join((newstring(c) for c in startstring))
```

If the replace string is not a complex function you can simplify to

```py
startstring = "ABCD WORLD"
transformed = [ f"[c:{16399+ord(c)-ord('A')}:0/]" for c in startstring ]
```

Comment: Is there a chance you can explain what this piece of code is doing, especially the "ord" part? so then I won't run into this problem later on? Thanks!

Comment: @BenRogers what do the python doc pages say about the buildin function `ord`